# How to run two requests parallel in two different tabs Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, request, es6-promise

I have a component in react which is requesting images from backend(django) in a loop,I received one image in response per request and it is happening in a loop so when it is rendered it is running in a video form that is rendering multiple images in a fast way that it becomes video and I have another component that register users, both components working perfect.

but when I run them parallel like video running in one tab and registering user in another tab they are not running parallel,I have to stop video request then the register request completes.How can I register user while the video request is running it should not wait for video to stop.

Video component is in **recognize.js** file

```
 runInfinite=()=>{


        let payload={
            iterator:this.state.iterator
        };

          axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/faceapp/process_image/', payload)
              .then(res => {
                  this.setState({baseimage: res.data});
                  this.setState({iterator:this.state.iterator+1})
              })


    };

render(){
      if (this.state.flag){
                this.runInfinite()
      }
      return(
            <div>
                  {this.state.baseimage?<img  src={"data:image/png;base64," +  this.state.baseimage}/>:null}
           </div>
           )
}
```

User register in **Register** Component:

```
 axios.post(' http://127.0.0.1:8000/faceapp/create_user/',payload)
                .then(res=>{

                    if (res.status===201){
                        this.setState({status:<img alt src={require('../assets/images/tick.png')} width="20" height="20"/>});

                    }


                    for (let i=0;i<this.state.images.length;i++) {

                        let formdata2=new FormData();
                        formdata2.append("user_image",this.state.images[i][0]);
                        axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:8000/faceapp/manage_user/'+res.data.id+'/',formdata2)
                            .then(res=>{
                                console.log(res)
                            });



                        for (let j=0;j<this.state.images[i].length;j++){

                            let formdata=new FormData();
                            formdata.append("user",res.data.id);
                            formdata.append("user_image",this.state.images[i][j]);

                            if (j!==0) {  // as first image is main so neglect main image in multiple images

                                axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/faceapp/create_user_image/', formdata)
                                    .then(res => {
                                        console.log(res)
                                    })
                            }
                        }


                    }
                })
                .catch(err=>{
                    this.hideLoader();
                    this.setState({status:<img alt src={require('../assets/images/cross.png')} width="20" height="20"/>});
                })
```

If the video request running in recognize.js file , how can I run register request in register.js file at the same time in other tab

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in parallel (aka. concurrent) using `Promise.all`.

```
let p1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    // first request 
    axios.post('url1', payload).then(res => {

            /** code **/
            resolve();
    })
})

let p2 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

    axios.post('url2', payload).then(res => {

        /** code **/
        resolve();
    })

})

let p = Promise.all([p1,p2]).then(()=>{
    // after completing both the requests 
})
```